# How to use the Profiles2 module for Drupal

Tags: 7, theming, users

I would like to use the Profiles2 module for Drupal 7 to create user profiles that are separate from user accounts.

I'm trying to find out what is the url for editing the user profiles created with the Profiles2 module? For example:

```
    http://www.example.com/url-for-profile-editing-page
```

And what is the template file I have to modify in order to cutomize this page?

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is dynamic, per-user and per-profile... for my site, it's something like the following: user/[user-id]/edit/[profile2-machine-name].

This would be different depending on

- the user whose profile is being edited
- the profile2 profile that is being edited for that user

Alternatively, of course, you might want to just go to your 'my account' page (at /user), click on 'Edit,' and then in the local menu tasks (under the edit tab), you can click on the profile2 profile you'd like to edit.

With regard to a template to change the page, I'm not sure if there is one. You could do a [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in a custom module to change the form values a bit, but you might want to look around the profile2 documentation or module itself to see how these pages are built.

Comment: thanks very helpful. inside the sites/all/modules/profiles2 there is a file called profiles2.tpl.php which is the to alter for theming.

Answer (score 0):

if the above answer did'nt worked for you the url may vary to this

```
http://[site_addres]/profile-[profile_machine_name]/[User_ID]/edit
```

Example: http://mysite.com/profile-main/1/edit

happy coding